# Why does gradle not run my shell script?

Tags: android, bash, shell, groovy, gradle

I'm almost certain i am overlooking something.

I have an android gradle project with a `build.gradle` file. Inside here, I specify the task:

```
task doSomething(type: Exec) {
    println("okay clearly you have got to be getting in here")
    commandLine 'sh /Users/dzt/Desktop/create_a_file_on_desktop.sh'
}
```

and that doesn't run at all. the shell file just literally does:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "hi" > /Users/dzt/Desktop/i_am_a_byproduct.txt
```

and i ran `chmod u+x` on it so it is executable (i double checked on regular bash shell).

I also tried to use the groovy command:

```
"cd ../ && sh /Users/dzt/Desktop/create_a_file_on_desktop.sh".execute()
```

which does not work either. I'm a little stumped. i do NOT see the output file. however, i do see my print statement in the gradle console.

What is going on here?

** EDIT **

okay, i drilled it down more ->

`cd ../` does not work at all. why is this? i need to use a relative path, at least relative to this directory

Comment: Just to make sure, have you tried it like this: `commandLine '/Users/dzt/Desktop/create_a_file_on_desktop.sh'` or in groovy: `"/Users/dzt/Desktop/create_a_file_on_desktop.sh".execute()`?

Comment: i think those will run. for some reason the `cd ../` does not run properly

Answer (score 4):

The call must be

```
commandLine 'sh', '/Users/dzt/Desktop/create_a_file_on_desktop.sh'
```

or else this is considered *one* command.  But you want to start the `sh` with the script as param.  On the other hand, since you have set the execute-bit, you can as well just call the shell script directly.

See http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html

Running `cd` like you want with `cd ../ && sh script` does also not work like this, since `&&` is a shell script command.  If you want to run like this, you have to run the shell and make it run as a command.  E.g.

```
commandLine 'sh', '-c', 'cd ~/scripts && sh myscript.sh'
```

Comment: Hello, what's the point of the -c flag please?

Comment: @FujoDJ It runs the given command. See `man sh`

Answer (score 1):

Gradle does not allow `cd` command for some reason. some commands just do NOT work using groovy.

instead, i used `cd` inside my shell script. that seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to put in the root level `gradle.build` file. The you need to write it like this, to actually be able to execute the task.

```gradle
task doSomething << {
    group 'yourGroupName'
    description 'Runs your bash script'
    exec {
        workingDir "$projectDir/../pathto/"
        commandLine 'bash', '-c', './bashscript.sh'
    }
}
```

Then you can execute with: `./gradlew -q doSomething`. In this case I used `bash`, but you can use any supported scripting shell, like `sh, perl, python` etc.